# Selecting a value based on a lookup value that fits between two values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a Worksheet in which I have two "tables" looking like this:

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is to do the following:

- Take the first two digit in Column D (for the first row 77)
- See which row in the table I to K the value from Point 1 fits in (in case of 77 it fits in between 77-99)
- Get the "Zone" value for that row
- Put that value into column E

I've tried Reading about VLOOKUP, INDEX and MATCH, but I can't really wrap my head around how to solve this. Unfortunately I'm used to SQL which won't help me all that much in this case.

What I would do in SQL (kind of) is:

```
SELECT [Zone] FROM ThisTable WHERE LEFT([D1],2) BETWEEN [Start] AND [End]
```

Is it possible to do this using a formula in Excel?

Comment: can you sort your data on column I? That would make your life much more easier with a VLOOKUP. Or if you need this layout visible, you can duplicate that table, sort and hide the second one and refer that from your formula

Comment: Hmm, I should be able to sort it whichever way is needed, yes. I'll try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Máté Juhász, `=VLOOKUP` can be used with some data shifting. From the [KB on vlookup](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Syntax - `VLOOKUP (lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])`

> range_lookup   (optional)
>
> A logical value that specifies whether you want VLOOKUP to find an
>   exact match or an approximate match:
>
> TRUE assumes the first column in the table is sorted either
>   numerically or alphabetically, and will then search for the closest
>   value. This is the default method if you don't specify one.
>
> FALSE searches for the exact value in the first column.

So if you sort by column J and do a vlookup to it with `TRUE` - you should get what you need.

So column E would have something like `=VLOOKUP((LEFT(D3,2)),$J$5:$K$19,2,TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Now it's becoming clearer an clearer. :)